# The math behind flappy bird

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

You may have heard of this game called flappy bird, but even if you haven't, you should be able to understand this basic game:

The player progresses through a series of obstacles. The probability of passing by any one obstacle is p, and the obstacles continue to come until the player fails to pass an obstacle, at which point the game ends. The player's score is the number of obstacles that he successfully passed before failing.

Here is the question I have about this game:

If the player plays the game, say, 100 times, how many times (on average) will he score a 1? a 2? etc. And what is his expected maximum score?

Comment: The player's score from a single game follows a geometric distribution:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution
Playing 100 times would just mean sampling 100 times from a geometric distribution.

Comment: The maximum score after playing one hundred times is something called an order statistic.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a geometric distribution.

The probability of getting through only the 1st obstacle is $p(1-p)$.

Getting through 2 obstacles and then failing is $p^2 (1-p)$. etc.

You could theoretically play forever, there is no maximum score.

The mean after many plays is $\frac{1-p}{p}$.

Comment: I think that playing one time means overcoming as many obstacles as possible before failing.  There is no maximum possible score.